# Adicionar classe utilizando JQuery em um form específico?

Tags: html, jquery

Como adicionar uma classe no botão da paleta que eu clicar em "curtir"?

Por exemplo, eu tenho várias paletas de cores, mas quando clico em curtir, todos os botões recebem a classe `.red`, eu queria que apenas no que eu cliquei recebesse a classe:

Meu HTML:

```
<form method="post" id="like">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$row->id?>" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" name="url" value="<?=Url::urlBase('palette/ajax/like')?>" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-light btn-sm">
        <i class="fas fa-heart"></i> <?=$row->likes?>
    </button>
</form>
```

O meu código ajax:

```
$('form#like').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $('#like input[name=url]').val(),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.success) {
                $('#like button[name=submit]').addClass('red')
            }
        }
    });
});
```

E aproveitando o tópico, gostaria de saber também como posso manter a classe red ativa mesmo se der reload na página? Já que eu não estou utilizando um sistema de login, aqui todos que entrarem no site podem dar os likes. Futuramente irei fazer pra descurtir.

Comment: Qual o problema da pergunta?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vê se te ajuda:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".botao-curtir", function(e) {
  //e.preventDefault();

  $(this).addClass('red');

});
```

```html
<form method="post" id="like">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$row->id?>" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" name="url" value="<?=Url::urlBase('palette/ajax/like')?>" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-light btn-sm botao-curtir">
        <i class="fas fa-heart"></i> <?=$row->likes?>
    </button>
</form>
```

- Se for de acordo com seu código, você pode adicionar uma classe ou um id no seu botão submit e, no retorno do AJAX, adicionar essa classe 'red' no botão, tendo como referência desse botão a classe ou ID que você deu a ele. **Veja:**

```js
$('form#like').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $('#like input[name=url]').val(),
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
      if (response.success) {
        $('.botao-like').addClass('red')
      }
    }
  });
});
```

- Para identificar um botão, você não precisa utilizar o atributo name (Geralmente, o atributo name serve para representar uma coleção de valores, enviados através de um formulário, para o servidor), você pode utilizar ID ou Classe.

Comment: Ficou do mesmo jeito aoskoask, quando clica adiciona em todas os botões, no caso tem várias paletas, veja :i.stack.imgur.com/k2gmH.png

Comment: Você colocou a classe botao-like no button ?

Comment: Sim, coloquei..

Comment: Está sendo apresentado algum erro no DevTools ?

Comment: Nenhum... Funcionou, só que do mesmo jeito... todos os botões acabam mudando, gostaria que só o que fosse clicado mudasse

Comment: Max, mas você colocou a classe em todos os botões ou só no que você quer mudar a cor ?

Comment: Jason, Tipo, essas paletas estão vindo do banco de dados, no caso eu usei um `foreach, então, se eu coloco a classe no botão, todos mudam...

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104725/discussion-between-jason-the-internship-and-max-fly).

Comment: Jason, aquele probleminha discutido no chat consegui resolver utilizando `var btn = $(this).children().last().attr('id');` com o teu código e com isto agora é 100% working oaksokas Obrigadão.

Comment: Nada! Show de bola, brothão.